# How does plot() decide where to plot data points on the x-axis?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to build a graph using three sets of data:
A predicted  "umbrella" and an observed "umbrella" where ratios are converted into an integer and then subset into vectors based on a value range.

```
ylrt    <- c()
yhatlrt <- c()
x       <- 0:678
y       <- 0:640
#
i = 0
while (i <= 12000)
{
    ylrt[[i+1]] <-  sample(x,2)
    i = i + 1
}
#
i = 0
while (i <= 30000)
{
    yhatlrt[[i+1]] <-  sample(x,2)
    i = i + 1
}
#
ylrt    <- unlist(ylrt)
yhatlrt <- unlist(yhatlrt)
#
table(ylrt)
#
table(yhatlrt)
#
```

To determine how often a ratio occurs in a given range, I took the length of the vectors and assigned the values, using `as.integer`, to unique variables and built a vector out of them.

```
ylrt  <- as_tibble(ylrt)
OLR1 <- as.integer(length(unlist(subset(ylrt, ylrt <=  25))))
OLR2 <- as.integer(length(unlist(subset(ylrt, ylrt >   25 & ylrt  <=  50))))
OLR3 <- as.integer(length(unlist(subset(ylrt, ylrt >   50 & ylrt  <=  75))))
OLR4 <- as.integer(length(unlist(subset(ylrt, ylrt >   75 & ylrt  <= 100))))
OLR5 <- as.integer(length(unlist(subset(ylrt, ylrt >  200 & ylrt  <= 400))))
OLR6 <- as.integer(length(unlist(subset(ylrt, ylrt >  400 & ylrt  <= 680))))
OLR7 <- as.integer(length(unlist(subset(ylrt, ylrt >  400 & ylrt  <= 680))))
OLR  <- c(OLR1, OLR2, OLR3, OLR4, OLR5, OLR6, OLR7)

# yhatlrt <- as_tibble(yhatlrt)
PLR1 <- as.integer(length(unlist(subset(yhatlrt, yhatlrt <=  25))))
PLR2 <- as.integer(length(unlist(subset(yhatlrt, yhatlrt >   25 & yhatlrt  <=  50))))
PLR3 <- as.integer(length(unlist(subset(yhatlrt, yhatlrt >   50 & yhatlrt  <=  75))))
PLR4 <- as.integer(length(unlist(subset(yhatlrt, yhatlrt >   75 & yhatlrt  <= 100))))
PLR5 <- as.integer(length(unlist(subset(yhatlrt, yhatlrt >  100 & yhatlrt  <= 200))))
PLR6 <- as.integer(length(unlist(subset(yhatlrt, yhatlrt >  200 & yhatlrt  <= 400))))
PLR7 <- as.integer(length(unlist(subset(yhatlrt, yhatlrt >  400 & yhatlrt  <= 680))))
PLR      <- c(PLR1, PLR2, PLR3, PLR4, PLR5, PLR6, PLR7)
#
```

The third data set is being used as a sort of grouping data for the x axis values and contains integers between 1 and 6.

```
IY  <- c()
#
z   <- 1:7
#
padvar <- length(unlist(ylrt)) - length(IY)
for (i in 1:padvar)
{
    new_value <- sample(z,1)
    IY          <- c(IY, new_value)
}
#
```

In order to plot the vectors, I then filled each with NA values until their lengths matched.

```
#
padvar <-length(IY) - length(OLR)
    for (i in 1:padvar)
        {
            new_value <- i*NA
                OLR = c(OLR,new_value)
        }
#
padvar1 <-length(IY) - length(PLR)
    for (i in 1:padvar1)
        {
            new_value <- i*NA
                PLR = c(PLR,new_value)
        }
#
```

Now the context is set, I noticed that upon plotting the data sets

```
plot(OLR~IY)
plot(PLR~IY)
```

several points are stacked upon the same x value while having the appropriate y axis value, and I have been unable to determine why. How exactly does R determine where to plot the data on the y axis that causes certain values to be stacked in this manner?

Comment: Please make sure your code can be run in a fresh R session. Currently variables such as `OLR6` and `ylr` are not defined so I get errors when running the code and cannot see the output. This makes it much more difficult to see what's going on to help you.

Comment: Fixed. I should have tested this in a new session before copying to the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the data that was plotted. R plots the data according to the scales shown on the x and y axes. The first time I ran your data, I got the following results:

```
ALL <- cbind(IY, PLR, OLR)
ALL[complete.cases(ALL), ]
#      IY   PLR  OLR
# [1,]  4  2296  927
# [2,]  4  2232  893
# [3,]  1  2240  892
# [4,]  3  2252  902
# [5,]  3  8771 7159
# [6,]  2 17624 9742
# [7,]  5 24587 9742
```

IY has two values of 4 with OLR values of 893 and 927, very close given the scale of your plot. Likewise the PLR values are almost the same, 2296, 2232. There are also two values of 3 on IY, but the matching values on PLR and OLR are very different.
[image: Plot]

The second time I ran you data I got results with no overlaps:

```
#      IY   PLR  OLR
# [1,]  2  2255  878
# [2,]  4  2198  918
# [3,]  5  2272  861
# [4,]  7  2176  875
# [5,]  1  8845 7095
# [6,]  4 17630 9875
# [7,]  6 24626 9875
```

The third time the "overlaps" re-appeared:

```
#      IY   PLR  OLR
# [1,]  1  2356  873
# [2,]  4  2296  915
# [3,]  1  2227  916
# [4,]  4  2146  839
# [5,]  6  8885 7097
# [6,]  5 17555 9856
# [7,]  6 24537 9856
```

Comment: Gotcha, so the issue lies primarily with the nature of the data and I was seeing the overlaps as an error even though it was operating exactly as designed?